# What is the right way to handle asynchronous behavior on Meteor's client side?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using Meteor specifically.

I'd like to make a call to a Facebook API (using Meteor's HTTP) to display pictures on Meteor's client side. I've seen the use of Fiber Futures, the storage of data in Sessions, and using the client to invoke a synchronous server call, but I'm not sure what is currently the best way or if other methods are now obsolete.

Comment: What is the question?  Asynchronous calls are always handled in browser-based client-side javascript with callback functions.

Comment: Doesn't Meteor have issues with asynchronicity? Seems to cause problems on Meteor's client side (so even providing callbacks don't necessarily update your model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common use case, acceptably solved, no need to think too deeply.

Making HTTP requests, and using the results.  If you get an URL back, save to session.  Set a template to be based on that session var, and it will automatically refresh once the callback updates the session.

http://docs.meteor.com/#http

```
HTTP.call("POST", "http://api.twitter.com/xyz",
          {data: {some: "json", stuff: 1}},
          function (error, result) {
            if (result.statusCode === 200) {
              Session.set("twizzled", true);
            }
          });
```

*******************************************8

To the rabid downvoters:  This is a brand new technology, rapidly changing, and just getting started. It is not hard to find info from a few months back that is inaccurate.  Let's be a little less quick to criticize newbies, until the flow of questions becomes harder to handle.  Just skip a question quicker if it bores you.